# Can new Double(String) ever return a null?

Tags: java

Given this code

```
final Double price = new Double(someString);
if(price != null <...>) {
```

Am I correct in assuming that price can NEVER be null here?

Comment: Yes it is never null.

Comment: If you separate the declaration from the assignment and have a try catch around the assignment then price might be null if `someString` is not a number (depending on what you do with the exception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the specifications: [section 15.9.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4):

> The value of a class instance creation expression is a reference to the newly created object of the specified class. Every time the expression is evaluated, a fresh object is created.

A constructor therefore can never return null. However, an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` may occur.

Answer (score 6):

It can thrown `NumberFormatException` but it can never be `null`, because you are using the `new` keyword.

Comment: I liked your answer and upvoted it, but gave the edge to the one that cites the actual spec.

Answer (score 1):

`new` never results in null, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can never be null. why do you doubt?

Comment: I doubted because the code explicitly checked for it, and I couldn't find that part of the spec where it was explicitly stated this was a useless check.